# Partial derivatives of $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have to examine the partial derivatives of $f $ in the point $(0,0)$.$$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $(x,y) = (0,0) $ } \\
\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}, & \text{if $(x,y) \neq (0,0) $}
\end{cases}$$

My question is: Do I apply $\lim_{x \to 0}$ and then use $y=0$ or vice versa?

(1a) $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}-0}{x-0} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{0}{y^2} = 0 $ (L'Hospital)

(1b) $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} =  \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}-0}{x-0}  = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{0}{x^3} = 0$

In this case it doesn't make a difference, but I don't think it's the same in general. Can you help me out?

Comment: What is this $f(x)$ you speak of? Isn't it a function of two variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're differentiating a function $ f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ in a point $ (x_0,y_0) $, then, by definition, you're seeking the limits:

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0) = \lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x_0 + h, y_0) - f(x_0,y_0)}{h} $$

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0) = \lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x_0, y_0 + h) - f(x_0,y_0)}{h} $$

A partial derivative is just a derivative of a function $ \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} ~~(x \rightarrow f(x, y_0)) $

Comment: well, this gives me exactly the same problem...

Comment: The problem is the same - the solution ought to be closer though

Comment: so it's for both, $x$ and $y$, $\lim_{h \to 0 } \frac{0}{h^3} $ in the end?

Comment: Well, it looks so